# How to embed scrollview to tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, foxit

I have a scrollview embedded in a cell of tableview. The scrollview is a Foxit PDF rendering engine.

I want to scroll vertically the tableview, horizontally the scroll view. I couldn't. As on the first GIF you see scrollview is bouncing even the content height and scroll height is equal. But at least paging is possible.

[image]

Then I added a custom scrollview over the Foxit view into the cell. The bouncing disappeared and scrolling up and down the scrollview scrolls the table view. That is good. But now I can not horizontally scroll and change pages of the PDF.

[image]

What to do how to "merge" the two approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play with `panGestureRecognizer` of scrollView and tableView. Install a relationship to prevent scrollView getting gestures before tableView `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: tableView.panGestureRecognizer)`.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot.